# How to capture exit code from another process

Tags: c#, process, exit-code

a c# app is called by another c# app and it exits out throwing exit code

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

how would the calling c# app capture this exit code?

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + process_name + s;

            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            myProcess.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use [`Process.ExitCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?